# Spring boot graphql endpoint not exposed

Tags: spring-boot, graphql

Depencies:

```
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-graphql:2.7.1
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.7.1
```

Simple controller with mock dao:

```
@Controller
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ProfileController {

private final ProfileDao dao;

@QueryMapping
public ProfileModel profile(@Argument String msisdn, DataFetchingEnvironment environment) {
    return dao.getProfile(msisdn);
}
}
```

Profile model is a simple record object.

Problem is there is no graphql or my custom http endpoint. I've tried following :

```
spring.graphql.path=/profile
graphql.servlet.mapping=/profile
graphql.url=/profile
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I have the same problem at the moment

Comment: With the new Spring Boot GraphQL starter, make sure your _schema.graphqls_ file is located under _resources/graphql_ folder, else you will get a 404.