# How to set up multiple GraphQL endpoints with Java Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphql, spring-boot-3, spring-boot-starter-graphql

I am using Java 21 with Spring Boot 3.2 and the

`implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-graphql:3.2.0"`

implementation of GraphQL.

I am currently able to send requests to `/graphql` and that schema file is located in `/resources/graphql/schema.graphqls`.

I want to create a second graphql endpoint called `/api`. How do I set up this second endpoint?

I found these:

[Multiple graphQL client endpoints in spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74210021/multiple-graphql-client-endpoints-in-spring-boot)

[Spring boot graphql endpoint not exposed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72943120/spring-boot-graphql-endpoint-not-exposed)

[Is there a way to expose 2 graphql endpoints using spring boot starter app graphql-spring-boot-starter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62202051/is-there-a-way-to-expose-2-graphql-endpoints-using-spring-boot-starter-app-graph)

but they are either unanswered or use kickstart graphql.

How do I set up multiple graphql endpoints in my Java project? And where should the schema files go for the second endpoint?

Thanks!